# UK TV 1980-1984 Sci-Fi - woman with no facial features, just a nose!

Tags: story-identification

Bit of a random one this but it scared me to death when I was a kid.  Only have vague memories but it was a TV program, just a one-off like *Tales of the Unexpected* or *The Twilight Zone*. I think it was sci-fi/horror themed. It would have been shown after 9pm between 1980-1984 in the Yorkshire TV region. It was British-made.

I just have this image of a woman with no face!  The eyes were skinned over and so was the mouth. So just a blank head with a nose. Scared me senseless and I just started crying when I saw it :) - my auntie teased me for years with it.  Woman with no face coming to get you, etc. etc.

Help me face my childhood demons and tell me the name of the show!

Comment: I don't know your story, but: in the original *Star Trek* series episode "Charlie X", Charlie made someone's face disappear and it was kind of disturbing.  When I was a kid, the shows were cut down to make room for more commercials, and that bit was cut... so I never saw this scary image as a kid.  Later, as an adult, I saw that episode uncut and that bit was in there, near the beginning of the episode.

Comment: This is a pretty common trope; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheBlank

Answer (score 6):

*Sapphire and Steel* might fit the bill.  In episode 2 Joanna Lumley did indeed appear as just a nose at one point:

[image: Sapphire and Steel screencap]

Comment: If correct, would be the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/movie-or-tv-series-episode-where-psychics-with-telekinetic-power-deal-with-sup

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a bit like the Twilight Zone episode It's A Good Life, from the original series and remade as the second segment of the 1983 movie.

In that episode, an all powerful boy, Anthony, at one point has made his sister's mouth completely disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but it isnt either of those. It was a british tv programme but thats about all i know.