# Scary TV series where a light spot would move around the floors, go underneath doors and evil would come

Tags: story-identification, tv

As a child I saw bits and pieces of a TV series that absolutely scared me. It was shown on Dutch television in the 80’s, English or US series.

I can’t tell what it was actually about. A light spot would move around the floors, go underneath doors and you know evil would come. People would be abducted if they were touched and taken to another place and time. No clue on the story.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28530/movie-or-tv-series-episode-where-psychics-with-telekinetic-power-deal-with-sup

Answer (score 12):

That sounds like the first serial of the [*Sapphire and Steel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapphire_%26_Steel) TV series. The timing is more or less right, and the malevolent entity was seen as a light spot that moved around the floor.  Rob and Helen's parents were abducted by it.

Not exactly advanced special effects by any means, but surprisingly spooky nonetheless.

You might also remember that the entity could be summoned by nursery rhymes, and the fairly memorable title sequence: